# parse() method in Xerces-J

Tags: java, parsing, xerces

I am looking into the Xerces JAVA parser and I would like to know what it is that actually goes on inside a `parse()` method? (I want to see some kind of source code, to be exact.)

Can anybody please tell me where I should look for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a [few samples here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/samples.html), perhaps they'll be of assistance?